# Non-integer powers in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

In a part of my term project I need to implement a formula using x86 assembly language. Problem is, it contains non-integer power values. I added a screenshot of the formula. All the terms except the width and current are known. I need to calculate width for a given current value or vice versa. For example, when i try to calculate current for a given width value, i end up with an expression like this:

[image: Formula]

width = 31.2 * (current)^1.38

(Assume thickness = 1 in formula)

The term with non-integer power value is annoying. I couldn't manage to express it in x86. We haven't seen anything about non-integers throughout the term. Any idea? Thanks for comments...

Comment: `a ^ b == 2 ^(B * log2(A))`; then try using `F2XM1` and `FYL2X`

Comment: Normally you'd just call `pow` from libc / libm (the math library from an ISO C implementation) to use a robust and efficient implementation, but I assume that's not available and you want to inline the calculation.

Comment: Unfortunately F2XM1 and others are not allowed. I think instructor wants us to use Taylor series or something like that. He said no need to calculate exact values.

Comment: @SavurduYarrani Is your task to write a program without using the FPU (this means: a program that would work on an 80386 without an 80387)?

Comment: related: [is there any way to calculate x^y in emu8086? (x is an integer and y is a float)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67374476/995714)

Comment: @Martin Rosenau Yes we are using emu8086. Instructor and assistants didn't say anything about 8087. All the course and laboratory contents is related only to 8086. Probably he will realize it is illogical to implement this formula in 8086 and edit the assignment.